# Can I make any conclusion from this insignificant t-test result?

Tags: t-test, paired-data

I am analysing the food intake rate of monkeys in a tree over the duration of their tree occupancy. I am looking at the intake rate in the first quarter of their occupancy duration and comparing to the last quarter of their occupancy, to see whether it stays the same, reduces, or increases.

I completed a paired t-test (after checking for normality), and was given an insignificant result (p>0.05).

Do I conclude that I cannot reject the null hypothesis that the means of Q1 and Q4 are the same and
"**therefore the intake rate has not changed, but has remained constant**"

OR

"**there is no sig. relationship between Q1 and Q4 as p>0.05, therefore I CANNOT conclude the intake rate has remained constant.**"

Comment: What is your null hypothesis for conducting the test? That will give you your answer.

Comment: Suppose there is a real difference btw Q1 and Q2. In view of your sample size and the variability of amounts eaten, you may not have had enough information to detect that difference. So all you can say is that you didn't detect a difference. // The reason for doing a 'power and sample size' procedure in advance of such an experiment is to have an idea before you start what the probability is of detecting a difference of a particular meaningful size.

Comment: @coconn41 How does that give the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest option 3.

> **The relationship was insignificant at p=0.05, so we are neither able to reject the null hypothesis of constant intake rates, nor accept the null hypothesis; the paired t-test is *inconclusive.***

Let's break down why your two suggestions are incorrect.

> therefore the intake rate has not changed, but has remained constant

Hypothesis testing cannot provide evidence in favor of the null. Along with power calculations, you can get evidence in favor of being so close to the null that there is not a practical difference, but you cannot prove the null. Using a high p-value as evidence in favor of the null is a common mistake.

> there is no sig. relationship between Q1 and Q4 as p>0.05, therefore I CANNOT conclude the intake rate has remained constant.

This seems to mix up the null and alternative hypotheses, but an insignificant p-value does not give evidence in favor of the alternative hypothesis.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you!